# kinesis connected to multiple shards - wont fully disconnect again

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-kinesis, aws-sdk-js

i have an issue where, if i connect to more than one shard, and call `client.destroy()`, the script keeps running, where i expect it to stop running, as no more connections should stay open.

im using `@aws-sdk/client-kinesis (3.369.0)`, and everything works, i can consume all my events, issue is only stopping the consumption again, i have removed all the unnessary parts of the code, like consuming, as there is no issues there.

setup:

```js
const region = "";
const accountId = "";
const streamName = ""
const consumerName = "";
const streamARN = "arn:aws:kinesis:" + region + ":" + accountId + ":stream/" + streamName;

const client = new KinesisClient({ region });

//recover a consumer or create a new one
const { Consumers } = await client.send(
  new ListStreamConsumersCommand({ streamARN })
);
let consumer = Consumers.find((i) => i.ConsumerName == consumerName);
if (!consumer) {
  const { Consumer } = await client.send(
    new RegisterStreamConsumerCommand({ streamARN, consumerName })
  );
  consumer = Consumer;
}
```

this works:

```js
// get shards
const { Shards } = await client.send(
  new ListShardsCommand({
    streamARN,
    streamName,
  })
);

//subscribe to shards
for (const shard of Shards) {
  const { EventStream } = await client.send(
    new SubscribeToShardCommand({
      ConsumerARN: consumer.ConsumerARN,
      ShardId: shard.ShardId,
      StartingPosition: { Type: "LATEST" },
    })
  );
  console.log("subscribed", shard.ShardId);
  break; // only subscribe to the first one..
}

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('stopping..')
  client.destroy();
}, 30000)
```

outputs this, and the script stops (as expected)

```
subscribed shardId-000000000000
stopping..
```

where as if i remove the `break` like so

```js
// get shards
const { Shards } = await client.send(
  new ListShardsCommand({
    StreamARN,
    StreamName,
  })
);

//subscribe to shards
for (const shard of Shards) {
  const { EventStream } = await client.send(
    new SubscribeToShardCommand({
      ConsumerARN: consumer.ConsumerARN,
      ShardId: shard.ShardId,
      StartingPosition: { Type: "LATEST" },
    })
  );
  console.log("subscribed", shard.ShardId);
}

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('stopping..')
  client.destroy();
}, 30000)
```

the output is

```
subscribed shardId-000000000000
subscribed shardId-000000000001
subscribed shardId-000000000002
subscribed shardId-000000000003
stopping..
```

but the script never stops, i could call `process.exit` that is not the point, im wondering what i have to do, for it to behave the same as if the break is there.